# Minkowski isometries

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, isometries

Consider theorem 1.7 from chapter III of 'Elementary differential geometry' by O'Neill. It says that:

**Theorem 1.7**: If **$\phi$** is an isometry of $E^3 $, then there exists a unique translation $T$ and a unique linear transformation $\psi$ such that $\phi = T\psi$.

Now, consider the relativistic interval defined on $R^n$ as usual, *i.e.* $I(x,y) = \sqrt{\sum (x_i - y_i)^2 - c^2(x_n - y_n)^2}$. We say that $\phi$ is a minkowskian isometry from $R^n$ to $R^n$ just in case for any x,y $\in R^n$, $I(x,y) = I(\phi(x), \phi(y))$.

The question is: does the **theorem 1.7** transfer immediately to the minkowskian isometry? That is, can we decompose uniquely the Minkowskian isometry into a translation $T'$ in Minkowski space and a linear transformation $\psi'$ (which would be represented by a Lorentz matrix) ?

Comment: Remark that your I(x,y) is not well-defined if what is under the square root is negative. But if you use I(x,y)^2, which is well-defined, to define minkowskian isometry, then the answer is yes.

Comment: Physicists normally define the interval without the square root. I have never seen it defined with the square root. Most people these days also choose units such that $c=1$. The group of linear transformations you're talking about is called the Lorentz group: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group .

Comment: Yes, the resulting group is known as the [Poincaré group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group). As a consequence of the property that you describe, it is a [semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) of the group of translations and Lorentz transformations (just the Euclidean group is the semidirect product of translations and rotations).